# how to set the permision for the document library in sharepoint

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library

I am new to sharepoint I need to set permission in the document library SharePoint user Who upload the documents from asp.net page. I need to know how to set the permission in document library from sharepoint.

Comment: you should give us more information? any special permission you want to set or just regular i.e giving the user to add documents etc

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually by going to Manage permissions on listitem. Then Click break inheritance and then grant the Permissions to created by user.

[image]

But i would recommend to do it from workflow.

To create workflow check:

http://johnliu.net/blog/2010/7/13/sharepoint-2010-configuring-list-item-permissions-with-workf.html

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/sharepoint-2010---configuring-list-item-permissions-with-workflow.aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Roji.Joy/how-to-set-item-level-permission-using-sharepoint-designer-2/

To edit document library permissions:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-server-help/edit-permissions-for-a-list-library-or-individual-item-HA101805400.aspx